# How Can i Download this video? Encrypted m3u8?

Tags: encryption, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Hello everyone For almost a whole month now I have been trying to download a file from a specific site

This is the link to the video
https://www.karaoke.co.il/api_play.php?type=clip&id=58370&autoplay=undefined&referer=karaoketv

The M3u8 files are split into 2 parts.

Video file
https://www.video-cdn.com/video/encrypt/750802ea0bc2d02fac93adeaa1398ec2/750802ea0bc2d...2-57d9518fae69

And an audio file
https://www.video-cdn.com/video/encrypt/750802ea0bc2d02fac93adeaa1398ec2/750802ea0bc2d...2-57d9518fae69

As far as I know there is a Key that needs to be entered in order to download the file.

And when I run the command in ffmpeg

I encounter many errors like:
Unable to open key file

Anyone who can download it.
I would be very happy if he would write me a code that works and explain to me how to do it

These are all the codes I have already tried

```
ffmpeg -decryption_key https://www.video-cdn.com/video/key/750802ea0bc2d02fac93adeaa13cde64 -i https://www.video-cdn.com/video/encrypt/750802ea0bc2d02fac93adeaa1398ec2/750802ea0bc2d02fac93adeaa1398ec2/video_720p.m3u8?token=R915dD-72351a7c-3dd1-4e58-b6c2-9cc813eeb183 -vcodec libx264 {output_file}
```

ffmpeg -decryption_key {key} -i {file} -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 d.mp4

ffmpeg -allowed_extensions ALL -protocol_whitelist data, file, http, https, tcp, tls, crypto -i "https://www.video-cdn.com/video/encrypt/f242d2da41d03b3955fb866efc5dbd59/f242d2da41d03b3955fb866efc5dbd59/video_720p.m3u8?token=R915dD-a1430cfc-0bda-46a0-a7e9-b15308875dc7" c copy -bsf: a aac_adtstoasc test.mp4 -decryption_key C:\ ffmpeg\enc.key

hlsdl -K "1a9625fb34a4afe0d5446138e9543563" https://www.video-cdn.com/video/encrypt/f242d2da41d03b3955fb866efc5dbd59/f242d2da41d03b3955fb866efc5dbd59/video_720p.m3u8?token=R915dD-be07b7e6-08aa-441b-afbd-5c7876409878

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZwHq.png)

Comment: Try to find it on Youtube and, if same company uploaded it there, then you can try download the video from that YT link.

Answer (score 0):

key:
base64:zPfjh0/g09EKjPIS4w37Kg==
Hex:ccf7e3874fe0d3d10a8cf212e30dfb2a

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
ffmpeg -decryption_key "https://www.video-cdn.com/video/key/750802ea0bc2d02fac93adeaa13cde64" -i "https://www.video-cdn.com/video/encrypt/750802ea0bc2d02fac93adeaa1398ec2/750802ea0bc2d02fac93adeaa1398ec2/video_720p.m3u8?token=R915dD-72351a7c-3dd1-4e58-b6c2-9cc813eeb183" -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy -c copy -crf 50 file.mp4
```

Comment: thats my error again and again and again
https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/8RdyHUcg8uSO.png?o=1

i really need to know how to download this
Some people download and do not tell how

Comment: @אורןNO decryption_key needs the actual key, not a URL.

Comment: so how can i find that?